# Can't import PyTorch even though it is installed

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch, python-venv

I installed the torch package on a Virtual Environment as recommended by my operating system
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZcLt.png)

As can be seen in the above image the package has indeed been installed.
I then proceeded to select the venv kernel in my jupyter notebook
Despite the above I cannot import the package torch:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

Thank you for observing and potentially helping solve this problem!

I tried:

- Installing torch on my regular environment, impossible due to OS prohibition
- Importing other libraries installed in a similar manner (matplotlib, numpy) and it worked
- Suggestions made in the other posts regarding a different installation command: python -m pip install -U pygame and it did not work as well

I would like to be able to import the torch package.